# iOS-like tab with Ionic Framework

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I was using ionic for a project but been not much satisfied with the UX for iOS. I mean how can I add this tabs (see picture) instead of the basic tab ionic comes with when you create a tab project ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de7uD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<ion-nav-buttons class="button-bar"></ion-nav-buttons>` directive to add buttons for every tab mentioned in your screenshot.

```
<ion-nav-buttons class="button-bar" side="left">
  <a class="button"
     ui-sref-active-eq="active"
     ui-sref="path1">
    Label 1
  </a>
  <a class="button"
     ui-sref-active-eq="active"
     ui-sref="path2">
    Label 2
  </a>
  <a class="button"
     ui-sref-active-eq="active"
     ui-sref="path3">
    Label 3
  </a>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

The `ui-sref` along with `ui-sref-active` directive makes sure that the tab with the active state is in focus

Comment: OK let me try this and come back